# Ubuntu 22.04 / Linux kernel 5.15.0 freezing on laptop with 1st gen Core i5, Intel graphics (ThinkPad T410)

Tags: boot, graphics, intel, thinkpad, 22.04

Lenovo ThinkPad T410 with Intel Core i5 M 520 (1st gen), 4 GB RAM (no errors with MemTest86), only integrated Intel HD Graphics. BIOS is updated.

When booting up an Ubuntu 22.04 USB drive on this computer and picking the option "Try or install Ubuntu", it appears to start up successfully, but a few seconds afterwards, it completely locks up. Mouse and keyboard are unresponsive, screen no longer updates. Alt+Fn+SysRq+{R,E,I,S,U,B} does not reboot the computer. Only way out is holding down the power button to force turn off.

If picking the option "Ubuntu (safe graphics)":

- The boot screen shows an error: `intel ips 0000:00:1f.6: failed to disable graphics turbo` but eventually it starts up without freezing and the OS can be installed successfully, with updates and third-party drivers turned on.
- The installed OS also freezes shortly after startup (at the login screen), just like the installer without safe graphics did.
- Managed to log in very quickly after a few tries, but the logged in OS freezes too, even with the "Ubuntu on Xorg" option instead of the default "Ubuntu" option which uses Wayland.
- The "advanced options" in the GRUB menu shows two Linux kernels: 5.15.0-25 and 5.15.0-30. The freezing problem occurs with either of them.
- Entering recovery mode, enabling networking and updating the system again (`apt-get update` and `apt-get upgrade`) did not update anything significant, and of course did not fix the problem.

This problem is not present on my other machines, newer and older. On this T410, older Ubuntu LTS versions like 20.04 and 18.04, as well as other updated Linux distributions like Fedora 36 and Arch, work with no problems. What is the cause of this freezing problem, and how can it be solved?

---

**Update:** Ubuntu 22.04.1 (Linux kernel 5.15.0-43) seems to not have this issue. Tested live USB drive on the same computer without installing, and after several minutes of use it has not locked up.

In case it still freezes, see below:

---

**The issue is with the kernel.** In recovery mode you can download and install a [newer one](https://kernel.ubuntu.com/%7Ekernel-ppa/mainline/) and then Ubuntu 22.04 will work on this computer. However this is not a solution, it is only a workaround.

Detailed steps:

- Install 22.04 with safe graphics. During installation, make sure you are connected to the Internet (wi-fi or ethernet).
- When booting, right before the installed OS starts up, press Esc until you see the GRUB menu.
- Select "Advanced options for Ubuntu", then select the first option that says "recovery mode".
- Select "network", then "yes".
- Select "root", then press Enter.
- Update list of packages and install Lynx command-line web browser: `apt-get update`, `apt-get install lynx`
- Use Lynx to open the Ubuntu kernel page: `lynx https://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline`
- Press End to go to the end of the page, find the newest version that does not say RC and select it. As of May 14 2022 that version was 5.17.7 (there is probably a newer one now).
- Download the four *amd64* deb files: `headers-[...]-generic`, `headers`, `image-unsigned`, `modules`. For each file to download, select it, press D to download, select "Save to disk" then press the left arrow to go back.
- Once those files are downloaded, press Q to quit Lynx and Y to confirm.
- Ensure the packages are present with the command `ls`, then install all of them at once: `dpkg -i *.deb`
- Reboot with the command `reboot`. Ubuntu will start with the new kernel.

Comment: Also give Xubuntu 22.04 a try. It is much lightweight. This way, you can figure out whether the desktop environment causes the issue, or something else (maybe the kernel or the graphics drivers) does.

Comment: @Archisman Panigrahi I tried Xubuntu 22.04 and Ubuntu MATE 22.04. The same freezing problem is still there, so it is not a fault of the desktop environment.

Comment: I would stick to 20.04 on older hardware.

Comment: @HomerSimpson That is a good idea, since 20.04 is supported until April 2025. However on even older hardware (Core 2 Duo), Ubuntu 22.04 is working properly without locking up, so whatever issue the OS or kernel has with the 1st gen Core i5 should be fixable.

Comment: Same boat here. Dell Latitude E4310, 1st gen Core i5 560M. It runs 21.10 smoothly, but when I did a fresh installation of 22.04 LTS, the system freeze randomly. Nothing can be done when this happens except holding down the Power button. When booting 22.04 with 'nomodeset' flag from GRUB, the random freezings are gone but the graphics is crippled. Update doesn't help. Had to rolled back to 21.10 from my backup image. [EDIT] I tried Pop!OS 22.04 and no more random freezes.

Comment: @dick same problem with a core 2 duo and nvidia 510 driver.after using ALT-PrtScr-B booting it no longer freezes...

Comment: kernel 5.17 does NOT solve the freeze. still get it with that kernel

Comment: same issue here with a pc (AMD Ryzen 5 2600x, GeForce GTX 1050 Ti and nvidia driver 470). Kernel 5.15.40 freezes, testing now with 5.17, 4 minutes in and no freeze yet

Comment: quick update, after 6hrs its still working, I guess this fixed it

Comment: I had a lot of frustrating freezes back in the day (like 2010 - 2013) with vanilla Ubuntu and Xubuntu as well, almost like one per week. It finally drove me away from Ubuntu / Linux altogether. Then in 2016 I bought a new computer with ECC memory and a compatible processor (whose integrated graphics I also rely on). I used vanilla Ubuntu 16.04 and 20.04 ever since, and had seen a single digit of freezes through these six-ish years, which is very relieving. Maybe the ECC memory has its benefits? (Yes I know, it's not an always viable option, as ECC compatible processors are expensive.)